# how to push in to gitlab instead of github

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I cloned the files in gitlab, created a new branch, edited the files and finally pushed it. But somehow it created a new repository, a new branch in my github and has nothing in my gitlab. What should i do

Comment: you need to change your remote origin to gitlab, `git remote add origin git@gitlab.com/UserRepo.git`.

Comment: If you cloned *from* GitLab, the push action would normally go *to* GitLab. See @AbidKhan's comment, but you might add the output of `git config --list --show-origin` to your question in case there's something odd with a global setting for a push URL. Other than that the answer is basically the same as "how do I drive to Tokyo instead of Osaka": you just choose that as your destination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your `git remote -v` output in the root folder of your local cloned repository.

If you had "cloned the files in gitlab", the URL should have been a GitLab one (`https://gitlab.com/...` or an SSH `git@gitlab:...`)

If not, you might see a GitHub URL.

Changing it to an existing remote GitLab one would be:

```
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/You/YourRepo
```

Comment: hehe, a minor spelling mistake. "remote" instead of "rmeote"

Comment: @AbidKhan Thank you for noticing it. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: no worries and most welcome!, we all are here to help each other :).